# Subring of $\mathcal O(\mathbb C)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathfrak A \subset \mathcal O(\mathbb C)$ be the subring generated by the nowhere zero analytic functions $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$.

Do we have a precise description of $\mathfrak A$? Is $\mathfrak A = \mathcal O (\mathbb C)$, or equivalently is there a holomorphic function $f$ such that $f \neq g_1 + \dots + g_r $ for all $g_1, \dots, g_r \in \mathcal O^*(\mathbb C)$ ?

For the moment, I only know that $\mathfrak A$ contains constants functions, and the functions on the form $z \mapsto e^f$ where $f$ is some holomorphic map. But I have really no idea how to solve this problem. Any hints?

Comment: My conjecture is that any entire function is the sum of two non-vanishing entire functions. Proof doesn't exist...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: A sum of two nonvanishing entire functions which are not multiples of each other must vanish at infinitely many points.  Indeed, $e^f+e^g$ vanishes whenever $f-g$ is an odd multiple of $\pi i$, and by Picard's theorem this must happen infinitely many times unless $f-g$ is constant.

Comment: @EricWofsey Well that explains why I couldn't prove it, thanks.

Comment: How is Picard's theorem used here?

Comment: @user114539: By [Picard's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem), there is at most one odd multiple of $\pi i$ that is not a value of $f-g$ unless it is constant.

Comment: An observation: If the identity function $z \mapsto z$ is in this ring, then every entire function is. Proof: If $z = \sum \exp(f_i(z))$ then $g(z) = \sum \exp(f_i(g(z))$.

Comment: Another observation: If $\mathfrak{A}$ contains a function which has some zeroes, but only finitely many, then it contains all functions. Proof: Let $\sum f_i(x) = g(x)$ with $f_i(x) \in \mathcal{O}^{\ast}$, and $g$ having $d$ zeroes. Write $g(x) = p(x) u(x)$ for $p$ a polynomial of degree $d$. Then $\sum f_i u^{-1} = p$, so $p \in \mathfrak{A}$. Now, if $q(x) = \sum f_i(x)$ then $q(x+1)-q(x) = \sum f_i(x+1) - \sum f_i(x) \in \mathfrak{A}$. Applying this $d-1$ times to $p$, we see that  $\mathfrak{A}$ contains a linear polynomial. Now we are done by my previous comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\def\fA{\mathfrak{A}}\def\cO{\mathcal{O}}$In this answer we will show that $\fA$ does not contain the identity function $z \mapsto z$. As already sketched in my comments above, this will imply that $\fA$ does not contain any function which has a finite, but non-zero, number of zeroes.

The key is an 1897 theorem of Borel due to uniqueness of representations of the above form. A good modern reference is [Chapter VII in Lang's Introduction to Complex Hyperbolic Spaces](https://books.google.com/books?id=kWTTBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA184#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Define an equivalence relation on $\cO$ by $f \sim g$ iff $f-g$ is the constant function. Suppose that $\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(f_i) = 0$ for $f_1$, $f_2$, ..., $f_n \in \cO$. Partition $\{ f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n \}$ into equivalence classes. Then Borel's result (Theorem 1.1 in Lang) says that, for each equivalence class $S$, we have $\sum_{f_i \in S} \exp(f_i)=0$. Since each equivalence class is of the form $(h+c_1, h+c_2, \dots, h+c_k)$ for some $h \in \cO$ and some constants $c_1$, ..., $c_k$, this is saying that essentially the only solution to $\sum \exp(f_i)=0$ is to look at $\sum \exp(h+c_i)$ where $\sum \exp(c_i)=0$. In particular, there are no singleton equivalence classes.

Let us reframe Borel's theorem. Let's say that a sum $\sum \exp(f_i)$ is in **reduced form** if no two $f_i$ are equivalent. We can always put any sum into reduced form by replacing $\exp(h+c_1)+\exp(h+c_2)$ by $\exp(h+\log(e^{c_1}+e^{c_2}))$ if $e^{c_1}+e^{c_2} \neq 0$, or by the empty sum if $e^{c_1}+e^{c_2}=0$.

> **Theorem** If $\sum_{a=1}^m \exp(f_a) = \sum_{b=1}^n \exp(g_b)$ with both sums in
>   reduced form, then $m=n$ and the $f_a$ and $g_b$ are the same up to permutation
>   and adding integer multiple of $2 \pi i$.

**Proof:** Partition $\{ f_1, \ldots, f_m, g_1+i \pi, \ldots, g_n+i \pi \}$ into equivalence classes. By the hypothesis that the sums are in reduced form, no equivalence class contains two $f_a$'s or two $g_b$'s.

Note that $\sum \exp(f_a) + \sum \exp(g_b + \pi i)=0$. By Borel's theorem, no equivalence class is a singleton. So all equivalence classes are of the form $\{ f_a, g_b \}$. In particular, $m=n$ and there is some permutation $\sigma$ and some constants $c_a$ such that $g_{\sigma(a)} +i \pi = f_a + c_a$. Now, Borel's theorem further tells us that $\exp(i \pi) + \exp(c_a)=0$. So $c_a$ is an integer multiple of $2 \pi i$. $\square$

We will now use this theorem to show that $z \not \in \fA$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $z = \sum_{a=1}^n \exp(f_a(z))$, and assume the sum is in reduced form.

Then, for any nonzero constant $h$, we have 
$$\sum_{a=1}^n \exp(f_a(z))+\exp(\log h) = z+h = \sum_{a=1}^n \exp(f_a(z+h)).$$
The right hand side is in reduced form. If none of the $f_a$ are constants, then the left hand side is in reduced form, and we have a reduced sum of $n+1$ terms equaling a reduced sum of $n$ terms, a contradiction. If one of the $f_a$ is a constant, cancel that term from both sides and once again reach a contradiction.

**Remark** As my comments show above, this rules out any function with finitely many zeroes. I think it should also rule out things like $f(z) = z(2^z+3^z)$, by considering the relation $$f(z+2) - 5 f(z+1) + 6 f(z) = 3 \cdot 3^{z} - 2 \cdot 2^z.$$
However, I do not have a good criterion for when a function is in $\fA$.

**Remark** Choose one function from each equivalence class. Then Borel's theorem shows that $\fA$ is the free $\mathbb{C}$ vectors space on the exponentials of these representatives. As a ring, $\fA$ is the group algebra of the abelian group $\cO^+/\mathbb{C} \cdot 1$, where $\cO^+$ means the additive group of the ring $\cO$.

**Remark** Note that $\fA$ is not closed under natural limiting operations. For example, for any $h \neq 0$, the function $z \mapsto \frac{e^{hz}-1}{h}$ is in $\fA$. But $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{hz}-1}{h} = z$ is not, even though the limit is uniform on compact subsets.

Comment: I can finally sleep now

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailled answer !!